# Getting error Column <ColumnName> does not belong to table after deploying

Tags: asp.net, datatable

Getting an error after deploying in server. It is running fine in local. I am creating a datatable from the same spreadsheet in both cases. While trying to use this data table I am getting **Error: Column  does not belong to table**

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dtTemp As New DataTable()
dtTemp.Columns.Add("ItemId") 'Create row for the error column
Dim dr As DataRow = dtMaterialBOM.NewRow() 'assign value for it
dr("ItemId") = lblItemId.Text
```